# Router to Wireless router (Packet Tracer)

Tags: routing, router, network, wireless, firewall

[image]

Hi, Can anyone help why I can't ping from my pc in office network to my laptop in guest network or wireless network. It is possible to ping from guest network to office but failed vice versa.

Main Router Configuration (updated)

```
Current configuration : 824 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!

Router#show running-conf
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 824 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Router
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 ip address 199.130.130.101 255.255.255.252
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet1/0
 ip address 199.130.130.1 255.255.255.192
 ip access-group Lobby out
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet2/0
 ip address 199.130.130.97 255.255.255.252
 ip access-group Lobby out
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet3/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
router rip
!
ip classless
ip route 199.130.130.64 255.255.255.240 199.130.130.98 
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Guest Router Configuration

```
(Internet)
IP address: 199.130.130.98
Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.252
Default Gateway: 199.130.130.97

(LAN)
IP address: 199.130.130.65
Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.240
Default Gateway: 199.130.130.65
```

Comment: Check the firewall on your PC.  It is often enabled by default.  Can you ping the LAN address (199.130.130.65)?

Comment: I have check that the firewall are off and I can't ping the LAN address (199.130.130.65) from my PC in office network

Comment: Could it be your access list?  You don't show it in your question.

Comment: I didn't do any access list yet.

Comment: It could be due to a NAT on the wireless.

Comment: interface GigabitEthernet1/0
 ip address 199.130.130.1 255.255.255.192
 **ip access-group Lobby out**

Comment: Tried this one. But still can't ping the wireless network

Comment: I don't see the contents of your access list in the configuration.

Comment: I deleted my access list from before.

Comment: You can test step by step:  1. Ping your default gateway.  Then ping Gi 2/0.  If you can't ping the LAN address from the PC, try pinging from the router.

Comment: @eccentriclearner Please don't use IP addresses that you don't own, even in an example. Use only addresses from RFCs 1918 & 5737.

Answer (score 1):

> "Hi, Can anyone help why I can't ping from my pc in office network to my laptop in guest network or wireless network. It is possible to ping from guest network to office but failed vice versa."

The router for the guest network appears to be a consumer router of some model, possibly a Linksys WRT300N which would be off topic for this site (Linksys is consumer equipment). The main issue would be that consumer routers such as the WRT300N have NAT and Firewall features enabled by default. To make your network work as you seem to want, you need to disable both NAT (Network Address Translation) and the Firewall features. You may also need to disable Wireless Isolation in order for wireless devices to communicate with each other and with wired devices.

It should be mentioned that your described network scenario completely undermines the design of a guest network since you seem to be trying to enable full access between all of your networks. You would accomplish the same by simply using a flat subnet and a wireless access point rather than router. To provide adequate security for your Office network, it should be protected by a firewall which should block all access into the Office network by default (and the same should be done for the Server network).

Any guest network should have no access to any other network by default and should be allowed only to the general internet but should have its own firewall to prevent anything on the internet from gaining access to the devices on the guest network, lest they be used for performing attacks or other undesirable things. Essentially your current design provides no/minimal security for any of your network assets.